# Upload Image using laravel with Form::model

Tags: php, laravel-4, image-upload

I am doing this in my blade:

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('files' => true , 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('profile_pic','Profile Picture',array('class'=>'control-label col-xs-2')) }}
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <img src="img_upload/{{ $user->profile_pic }}" alt="Image not find( {{ $user->profile_pic }} )"style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>
            {{ Form::file('profile_pic') }}
        </div>
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And I get that file using

```
$files = Input::file('profile_pic');
return Response::json([
        'success'=> false, 
        'errors'=>[$files]]);
```

I'm returning JSON because just want to make sure that image can get in controller, but it returns

> {"success":false,"errors":[null]}

If I want to try get the original name like this:

```
$filename = $files->getClientOriginalName();
```

I get error with message:

```
message: "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object"
type: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException"
```

Did I do something wrong ? Is it not possible to use `Form::file` in `Form::model`?

I was searching issues like this but I can't find solution, many people use `Form::open`

Comment: what does `Input::has('file')` return when you post the form?

Comment: If `$files` returns `null`, you will be getting error message for `getClientOriginalName()` function. You can use `Form:file` in `Form::model`. I don't see `route` at your form btw.

Comment: Jeemusu it's return "false"; 

Khay : My route is correct the prove laravel running in my controller and return the json from my controller i was do like this :
Route::post('editnewuseradmin', 'UserAdminController@saveUser');